# Request a new password mail without any content inside of the mail.

Tags: users, emails, authentication-authorization

I got a problem. When I want to request a new password due to password forgotten, the system definitely send a mail to my email address. But, this mail is without any content inside. 
I check the Configuration->People->Accounting Settings. I already setup all the content. But, I can't get any content. 
Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

admin/config/people/accounts
Check this section make sure this is not empty.

Comment: Hello, thanks your reply. I am for sure this section existed on my settings. Do you know the other causes?

Comment: Sorry not sure for any other cause until I see the problem.

Comment: Hello, if I let you enroll a account on my site. Would you like to help me?

Comment: By the way, I use mimimail the module. Will it affect the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I got fixed. The problem is on "wysiwyg" and "mimemail" the both modules. I adjust wysiwyg configuration. Here is my mimemail setting and I use advanced HTML. Then, I go into wysiwyg configuration. The both configuration I show the below pictures. Thanks.

[image: The wysiwyg configuration]
[image: The mimemail setting]